# Migration issue from TFVC to GIT

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

While cloning from TFVC to Git by using `git-tfs clone`, I am able to clone the code with changeset ids, but I am able to see only .git folder, not able to see other files and folders after cloning.

Comment: are there branches set up on the repo? Check gith `git branch -a`. If there are branches, checkout the one you would like to use with `git checkout some-branch` and then you should be able to see the files on that branch.

Comment: By the way, I'm not familiar with git-tfs.... that's just basic git workflow.

Comment: Please share the exact command that you are run and the exact output.

Comment: Hi Shayki, iam using "git-tfs clone repourl

Comment: Hi eftshift, thanks for Answer, actually there are few folders in the TFS branch, but when i cloned them, iam able to see .git folder, but unable to see the files , now iam able to see with "git branch -a" but there multiple folders and sub folders.

Comment: Hi Shayki, after cloning is done i need to push them to git server, can i get all folders and subfolders after push is done, if the file are in hidden in my local machine when i cloned them..can you plz help me.

Comment: Important terminology note: "TFS" is not a version control system. TFS is a platform that supports two types of version control systems, **TFVC** and Git.