# Azure DevOps TFVC to Git Migration

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

We are looking into the possibility of migrating from TFVC to GIT in Azure DevOps. There is a [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-TFVC?view=azure-devops) that looks like it should work for us, but it will not move the source code to the repository it creates. Our TFVC source tree resembles the below structure.

- $/Contoso
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1/Main (Branch)
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1/Main/Source (folder with source code)
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1/Main/Documentation (project documentation)
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1/Dev (Branch)
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1/Dev/Source (folder with source code)
- $/Contoso/GreatApp1/Dev/Documentation (project documentation)

At the very least, I would like to convert the Main branch with documentation and source code. We have 40-50 projects that follow this structure under a single project collection, so ideally I am hoping to do this using this tool without having to rebind source control in all of the different projects. Is what I'm wanting to do possible?

Comment: The answer is probably in the last line of the link you gave or in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git#advanced-migrations Try https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Comment: You mentioned "it will not move the source code to the repository it creates", could you let us know what error did you get?

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592193/migration-issue-from-tfvc-to-git
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957700/how-to-migrate-tfvc-to-git-including-history
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312097/tfvc-to-tf-git-migration-repo-organisation-incl-multiple-solutions-and-build

Answer (score 1):

The import experience is optimized for small, simple TFVC repositories or repositories that have been prepared for a migration. This means it has a few limitations.

1. It only migrates the contents of root or a branch. For example, if you have a TFVC project at `$/Fabrikam` which has 1 branch and 1 folder under it, a path to import `$/Fabrikam` would import the folder while `$/Fabrikam/<branch>` would only import the branch.
2. The imported repository and associated history (if imported) cannot exceed 1GB in size.
3. You can import up to 180 days of history.

If you want to attempt an advanced migration with [Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), that project provides documentation on how to do a migration from TFVC to Git, [cloning a single branch with history](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md#clone-just-the-trunk) or [cloning all branches with merge history](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md#clone-all-history).

let’s follow the migration guide and execute the clone command:

```
git tfs clone {TFVC repo URL}
```

Get all branches:

```
git tfs branch –init --all
```

For each branch, run these commands:

```
git checkout branch

git log -1

git tfs pull -c=changesetNumber
```

Create a new repo in the azure devops and get the repo URL. Then setup the git repository upstream:

```
git remote add origin {New repo URL}
```

Finally you push all your local changes to the Remote.

```
git push origin -u -all
```

Useful link:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/centralized-to-git
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git

Comment: The command you posted for grabbing all the branches has a typo in it (`--init` and not `-init`).

Also, this command is grabbing the entire history and so, so why it's required to grab all the changesets at hand by providing the changeset number?

The version used: `git-tfs version 0.32.0.0 (TFS client library 16.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit)`